Calculating the height of a kite, given the wind speed, the rate of paying out the string, and the distance to the point directly under it
A problem from an old book:

A three-mile wind blowing on a level is carrying a kite directly away from a boy. How high is the kite when it is directly over a point 100 feet away and he is paying out the string at the rate of 88 feet a minute?

What doesn't make sense to me is that a "3-mile wind", which I presume is a 3mph wind, is 264 feet/min. So how could they be paying out the string at 88 f/min, if just the speed in the x direction is carrying the kite at 264f/min. Since the string is being elongated as the hypotenuse of the triangle, it should be growing faster than just the x direction.
Is there some well known formula for transferring wind speed to kite speed? What am I missing here? I presume the solution can't be too complicated since this is an elementary book. Thanks for any help.

I suppose the kite's surface is perpendicular to the string, and so if the kite were straight above him then he would be paying out at $0$ f/min. The ratio of speeds then admittedly tells you the slope of the string, from which you can deduce the height of the kite. Though I must say it's not so clearly formulated.

I agree that calling a three mph wind a three mile wind is poor. For your other question, the string is on the hypotenuse of a triangle which is longer than the horizontal distance so it doesn't have to change as rapidly as the shorter distance.

note that the book was published in 1931. Meanwhile, the brief chapter has plenty of illustrations. https://archive.org/details/calulusforthepra000526mbp/page/n65/mode/2up

The simplicity of the problem statement requires you to make simplistic assumptions.
In reality, the kite cannot move at the same velocity as the wind. If it had the same horizontal speed, it would be unable to produce lift without falling (and therefore would have a vertical speed the wind doesn't have). But trying to figure out the velocity of the kite (horizontal or vertical) as a function of the speed of the wind would require information not provided or implied by the problem statement. So we ignore these facts of physical reality.
Also in reality, the string between the child and the kite would be curved: a catenary curve if only its own weight is involved, or some other curve if it is also influenced by the wind. Of course, in reality the string would also be pulling the kite down and in a horizontal direction opposite the wind. Again, the problem statement does not enable us to quantify these effects, so we ignore them.
Therefore we assume that the only motion of the kite is the motion described in the problem statement, $3$ miles per hour in a horizontal direction,
and that the string goes straight from the child's hand to the kite at all times, so the child pays out the string just fast enough to match the rate of increase in the distance to the kite.
The problem statement then becomes:

A kite is moving at a constant speed $264$ feet per minute in a straight line past a point $C$ (the child's position). The point $P$ is the point on the line nearest to $C$.
At the moment when the kite is at the point $K$ which is $100$ feet from $P$ in the direction of the kite's motion, the distance from $C$ to the kite is increasing at the rate $88$ feet per minute. What is the distance $CP$?

So at this particular instant in time -- let's call it $t=0$, $t$ measured in minutes -- you have a right triangle $\triangle CPK$.
Let's measure all distances in feet and all velocities in feet per minute.
Let $x(t)$ be the kite's distance from $P$ at time $t$,
with $x(0) = PK = 100$.
Let $y$ be the distance $CP$.
Let $s(t)$ be the length of the string at time $t$, with $s(0) = CK$.
Now here's a correct intuition: if we hold one leg of a right triangle constant and increase the length of the other leg, the hypotenuse increases at a rate less than the rate of increase of the leg. Your intuition, which said the hypotenuse must increase faster, was incorrect.
(The length of the hypotenuse is indeed greater than the length of the leg, but the length is not $88$ feet per minute; the rate of increase of the length is.)
Specifically, for this problem we have $s(t)$ as the hypotenuse and $x(t)$ as the leg that is increasing. Then
$$ s(t) = \sqrt{(x(t))^2 + y^2}. $$
Use the chain rule (twice!) to find the derivative of the right-hand side.
We then find that
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm ds(t)}{\mathrm dt} 
 = \frac{x(t)}{\sqrt{(x(t))^2 + y^2}} \frac{\mathrm dx(t)}{\mathrm dt} 
$$
As long as $y \neq 0$, the absolute value of $\frac{x(t)}{\sqrt{(x(t))^2 + y^2}}$ is always less than $1$, and therefore $s(t)$ (the hypotenuse) grows slower than $x(t)$ (the leg).
We happen to know from the problem statement that at time $t=0$,
$\frac{\mathrm ds(t)}{\mathrm dt} = 88$
and $\frac{\mathrm dx(t)}{\mathrm dt} = 264$.
Also, we know that $x(t) = x(0) = 100$ at time $t=0$.
We therefore know that
$$ 
88 = \frac{100}{\sqrt{100^2 + y^2}} \times 264.
$$
Solve for $y$.

(You can check your answer on page 329 of the textbook when you are ready.)

Just saw this solution. Solved it myself with the hint that the hypotenuse grows slower. Made me keep the height as constant, and came to this. Thanks for the help.

Edit: With the link to the book at hand it seems my assumptions are not the ones intended there. Those are covered by DavidK's answer. Interestingly though, the answer given by this method is the same. This is because in both cases the height is precisely that which renders the component of the wind velocity parallel to the string equal to the speed at which the boy is paying out. So I guess we'll never know who actually has the correct interpretation, but I argue that the formulation gives the impression that the height is varying :)
For this answer I make three assumptions:

the kite is moving up and away from the boy radially, so the slope of the (straight) string with respect to the ground is constant;
the kite's surface remains perpendicular to the string;
the speed of the kite is the component perpendicular to its surface of the velocity vector of the wind.

Let $\kappa$ be the slope of the surface of the kite with respect to the ground, so that if the kite is directly above the boy then $\kappa=0$.  Then $\theta = \arctan\kappa$ is the angle between the velocity vector of the wind and the surface of the kite.  The normal component to the kite surface of the wind's velocity is then
$$ s = w\sin\theta = \frac{w\kappa}{\sqrt{1+\kappa^2}} \text. $$
This is also the speed of the string.  Solving for $\kappa$ yields
$$ \kappa = \frac{s}{\sqrt{w^2-s^2}} \text. $$
The slope of the string is $1/\kappa$, and with $d$ the distance on the ground, the height is $h = d/\kappa$.  Alltogether,
$$ h = \frac ds\sqrt{w^2-s^2} \text. $$
Of course in real life the weight of the string and kite start to make a significant difference at $100$ feet.

That makes sense, but what I still don't understand is why is the slope 1/k?

@skugz If the slope of a line is $m$, the slope of a line perpendicular to the first line is $-1/m$. This is taught in precalculus and is easily confirmed by drawing right triangles under the two lines with legs parallel to the coordinate axes. Of course this assumes the string is perpendicular to the kite's surface, which is a completely unwarranted assumption.

@skugz But this fact actually is irrelevant, because we have no need to assume anything about the slope of the kite. Your intuition that the hypotenuse must grow faster than the $x$ coordinate is incorrect and has misled you. It is actually the opposite: the hypotenuse must grow slower.

@DavidK The reason our answers differ is because I interpreted "directly away from the boy" as meaning up and away in a straight line; so the angle between the (straight) string and the ground is constant. Looking at the context of the book ("differentiation of the appropriate formula and division by $dt$ will then give the formula involving the rates"). I think your answer is the correct interpretation, but I did not have the link to the book at the time of answering.

You are right though that it is not $s = w\kappa$ but $s = w\sin\kappa$. Stupid mistake which I will now correct. But otherwise I believe what I say makes sense under the assumption that 1) the kite is moving radially away from the child, and 2) that the speed of the kite is the component of the windspeed vector perpendicular to its surface.

I think the phrase "directly away" was meant to convey that the kite is traveling along a straight line that passes directly over the child's position, but if we take a more literal interpretation then we have to imagine that somehow the kite is not just carried by the wind but is traveling upward so that the direction of travel relative to the air mass is perpendicular to the string.

So in your interpretation, if you consider the kite as a flat plate perpendicular to the string, at the time specified in the question and shortly thereafter there is a point at which the kite intersects a horizontal line at $283$ feet altitude. That point of intersection moves at $3$ miles per hour. It's also the location of the kite in my interpretation. Either way, the radial distance is increasing at the same rate, therefore the answers should be the same. It does make one wonder what the author was really thinking.

I think what they mean is that the KITE with respect to the boy goes away at a rate off 88ft/min but the wind speed is 3mile/hr
i dont think there is any issue in question as its totally posible that (and a must) speed of wind is more than the speed of kite so that there is a net force (thrust) on the kite which is keeping it in flight
if the speed of kite and wind become same there will be no net force on the kite causing it to fall out of the sky
U can think of it as sail boat it will only go as fast as the wind (till there is a relative motion) after the boat gains the speed of wind it wont increase its speed
Here in this case the boy is the one who controls the speed of kite, if he let goes then the kite will gain the speed of wind
U are right at the part which implies that the length of string will be the hypotenous of the right triangle formed by the vertical distance from ground and the distance from boy
I dont think there is a direct formule to calculate wind speed and kite speed on an elementary level at least

The string only has to span the distance from the child to the kite, which does not increase as fast as the kite moves. The kite is perfectly able to move at $264$ feet per minute horizontally while its distance to the child is increasing at only $88$ feet per minute (at one point in time; later the distance will grow faster).

I actually misunderstood part of the problem's stated information, which temporarily invalidates this answer. I thought the rate of change of the string was constant, but it is only 88 ft/min when the kite's horizontal distance is 100 ft from the boy. I will fix this answer as soon as I can.
To answer your question in the second paragraph of how the string length (hypotenuse) is growing slower than its $x$-component, my intuition is that the kite must be falling downward. That way, even though the horizontal position of the kite is increasing by $264\;\text{ft/min}$, the total string length between the kite and the boy is only increasing by $88\;\text{ft/min}$ because the kite falling downwards brings it somewhat closer to the boy.
Now for the actual problem. Let’s first visualize the right triangle constructed from the positions of the boy and the kite:

In the picture above, side length $a$ represents the horizontal position of the kite, side length $b$ represents the height of the kite, and side length $c$ represents the length of the string from the boy to the kite. We also know that the rate of change of $a$ is $264\;\text{ft/min}$, and the rate of change of $c$ is $88\;\text{ft/min}$. Now our goal is to figure out the value of $b$ when $a=100\;\text{ft}$. We can try using the Pythagorean theorem:
$a^2+b^2=c^2\\
b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}\\
b=\sqrt{c^2-\left(10\right)^2}\\
\boxed{b=\sqrt{c^2-100}}$
Unfortunately, this is as far as we can get. Without knowing more direct information on the kite's position, we can't really do anything with the given rates of change to figure out the missing variable $c$ to solve for $b$. To show why this is the case, I decided to set initial positions for the boy and the kite.
Let's say the boy's position is $(0,0)$, and this stays constant. Let's also set the initial position of the kite at $(0,500)$, which is $500\;\text{ft}$ directly above the boy's head, and let's use the variable $m$ to represent time in minutes. Now, we know that the horizontal position of the kite starts at $x=0$ and increases by $264\;\text{ft/min}$, which can be written as $264m$. We also know that the string length (hypotenuse of the right triangle) is initially $500\;\text{ft}$ and increases by $88\;\text{ft/min}$, which can be written as $(500+88m)$. Therefore, the height of the kite at any time can be found using the Pythagorean theorem:
$\text{Height of kite}=\sqrt{\left(500+88m\right)^2-\left(264m\right)^2}\;\;\;{m\ge 0}$
The equation is also graphed below with the vertex and intercepts labeled (note that the $x$-axis is scaled differently than the $y$-axis to make the graph easier to analyze):

Notice that the height of the kite peaks at a mere $0.71023$ minutes of flight, then makes a sharp descent towards the ground. For one, this explains the amusing question title in which the author curses the wind for making the kite fall so quickly. But more importantly, this supports our intuition from earlier that the kite must be falling downward in order to compensate for how slowly the string length was increasing in comparison to the kite's horizontal position. The point is, this analysis would have been impossible without knowing some direct information about the kite's position (in our case it was the kite's starting position), so I think the problem as stated in the book is not solvable.
For your reference, I've linked another Desmos graph where you can manipulate the kite's initial height and the time traveled to see how it affects its path.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fepjbjxvvb

OP made an incorrect statement: "Since the string is being elongated as the hypotenuse of the triangle, it should be growing faster than just the x direction." On the contrary when one leg of a right triangle grows and the other leg remains a constant length, the hypotenuse grows slower that the leg, a fact you can easily verify. There is no need for the kite to fall, and indeed if we supposed that it could fall, the problem would indeed not be solvable. You should not assume that every statement in an MSE question is correct.

@DavidK You're right, the hypotenuse does grow slower than the horizontal leg. But I imagined that as the horizontal leg kept growing at a constant rate to infinity, the growth rate of the hypotenuse would eventually have to increase to keep maintaining contact with the endpoint of the leg. If the growth rate of the hypotenuse stayed constant, then eventually it wouldn't be able to maintain contact with the leg, and the leg would have to shift vertically to compensate. I thought this represented the kite falling. Would you mind explaining where exactly I went wrong in using this reasoning?

The $88$ feet per minute is described as the rate the boy is increasing the string when the kite is horizontally $100$ feet away. The boy will have to lengthen the string faster when the kite is farther.

@DavidK Ohhh, that makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!

@DavidK No worries, I'll edit the post right now to show that I misunderstood the problem, then I'll probably fix my answer later this week using your solution and the textbook answer as a guide.

That's enough of an edit to clear a downvote, especially with the very clear added statement about assumptions.

Thanks, you helped a lot with the statement that the hypotenuse grows slower. I had in my mind that the triangle formed remains similar to the original one. When height is taken as constant, the hypotenuse c grows by the equation dc/dx = x/(√(x^2 + h^2)). When putting the ratio of the speeds as dc/dx=88/264=1/3 and x=100, I get h=282.84, which is the solution in the answers in the book. Thanks a lot for the help.

No problem, I’m glad this helped you understand and solve the problem. I definitely think the author could have worded it better ;)
